# how to print all the output at the end of the while loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I already solved this with list.append() function however my instructor told me to just use the basic python functions. Here is my code:

```
    a = 0
    b = 0
    s = 0
    x = str(s)

    print ('Enter the first number: ', end = '')
    c = input()
    a = int(c)
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        print ('Enter the next number (0 to finish): ', end ='')
        n = input()
        b = int(n)
        if b != 0:
            if b == a: 
                x = ('Same')
            elif b > a:
                x = ('Up')
            elif b < a:
                x = ('Down')
            a = b
            s = x
        else:
            finished = True

    print (str(x))
```

I am aiming to print (e.g. Up Down Up Down Same in comparing the input integers) in one line at the end of the while loop. Let me know how can I improve my code. Thank you very much

Comment: It would be helpful to show your version using `list.append()`. Did your instructor give any hint what they want? `list.append()` doesn't seem that exotic.

Comment: a = 0
b = 0
demands = []
 
print('Enter the first number: ' , end = ' ')
c = input()
a = int(c)

finished = False
while not finished:
    print('Enter the next number, 0 to finish: ' , end = ' ')
    n = input()
    b = int(n)
     
    if b != 0:
      if b == a:
        demands.append ('Same.')
      elif b > a:
        demands.append('Up.')
      elif b < a:
        demands.append('Down.')
      a = b
    else:
        finished = True
print (demands)

Comment: I'm suggesting editing your question to include this information, it seems intrinsic to what you're asking.

Comment: List is the most basic data structure in Python!!!, then just concatenate your every output in a string, and show that summary string at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string concatenation to get the result you want without using a list:

http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python

I'll give you two hints on how to do this for your program:

1. Initialize x as an empty string by replacing

   ```
   x=str(s)
   ```

   with

   ```
   x=""
   ```

   There is no need for it to begin as the string "0", which str(s) does since s is 0.
2. Instead of saying

   ```
   x=('SAME')
   x=('UP')
   x=('DOWN')
   ```

try saying

```
    x=x+'SAME'
    x=x+'UP'
    x=x+'DOWN'
```

I removed the parentheses because they are not necessary.

As for style, it is good practice to name your variables as useful things instead of just letters. Last staement in an if/else chain that covers all bases should just be else. Best of luck to you sir

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what result you're looking for, but perhaps this works:

```
a = 0
b = 99
result = ""

a = int(input('Enter the first number: '))

while b != 0:
    b = int(input('Enter the next number (0 to finish): '))

    if b == a:
        result += ' Same'
    elif b > a:
        result += ' Up'
    elif b < a:
        result += ' Down'
    a = b

print(result.strip())
```

Output:

```
Enter the first number: 12
Enter the next number (0 to finish): 12
Enter the next number (0 to finish): 12
Enter the next number (0 to finish): 1
Enter the next number (0 to finish): 1
Enter the next number (0 to finish): 5
Enter the next number (0 to finish): 0
Same Same Down Same Up Down
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply initialize `x` with an empty string and keep concatenating to it.

```
a = 0
b = 0
s = 0
x = ''

print('Enter the first number: ', end='')
c = input()
a = int(c)
finished = False
while not finished:
    print('Enter the next number (0 to finish): ', end='')
    n = input()
    b = int(n)
    if b != 0:
        if b == a:
            x += 'Same\n'
        elif b > a:
            x += 'Up\n'
        elif b < a:
            x += 'Down\n'
        a = b
        s = x
    else:
        finished = True

print(str(x))
```